# Multivariable polynomial interpolation via evaluations from entrywise powers of a point

Tags: reference-request, polynomials

I am interested in multivariate polynomial interpolation.  Within computational complexity theory, I use it to create efficient reductions between counting problems.  In the univariate case, there is a useful characterization of when such polynomials of degree $d$ can be interpolated: $d+1$ distinct evaluation points (since the coefficient matrix of the corresponding linear system is [Vandermonde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)).  In the multivariate case, it is my understanding that a similarly useful characterization is not known.  However, I often encounter the following special case (for which I hope more is known).

For $n \ge 3$, let $$p \in \mathbb{C}[X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n]$$ be a homogeneous polynomial of [(total) degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#Extension_to_polynomials_with_two_or_more_variables) $d \ge 1$, which has $N = \binom{d+n-1}{n-1}$ coefficients.  Given a point $$x = (x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n,$$ consider the set of points $$S = \left\{\left(x_1^k, x_2^k, \dotsc, x_n^k\right) \in \mathbb{C}^n~\middle|~0 \le k \le N - 1\right\}$$ defined by taking [entrywise (aka Hadamard or Schur)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29) powers of $x$.

Given the evaluations of $p$ at all the points in $S$, we have a linear system whose coefficient matrix is Vandermonde (which follows from the definition of $S$).  We can interpolate $p$ iff this matrix is invertible iff the monomials of $p(x) = p(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n)$ are distinct.  For $n=2$, these monomials are distinct iff the points in $S$ (when viewed as length-two vectors) are pairwise linearly independent iff neither $x_1$ nor $x_2$ is $0$ and the ratio $x_1 / x_2$ is not a root of unity.  This is a useful characterization.

### Question

What about a useful characterization when $n > 2$?

> For any $n \ge 3$,
> is there a useful characterization of $x$ with the property that,
> for all degrees $d \ge 1$ and all homogeneous polynomials $p$ of (total) degree $d$,
> the monomials of $p(x)$ are distinct?